# how to integrate square card reader api with xamarin forms?

Tags: api, xamarin.forms, square-connect

I want to integrate square card reader device API in xamarin forms. Is there any way to do this in xamarin forms for both android and iOS cross platform application?

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the card readers directly from your mobile application, Xamarin forms or not. Currently the only way you would be able to use the card readers with your app is with the register API, which would switch to the Square Register app when processing payments. Reqd more here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-overview/

Comment: Thanks i will check

Comment: karan, have you found anything. . . . I also want to integrated in-app payment using square for xamarin.ios and android but not able to find any related resource on net.  . . . .